# Python pillow: problem with threshold transparency

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert `png` to `bmp` 256 8 bits indexed colors, but I can't figure out how to set a threshold to make partial transparent pixels become transparent, original and result:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def convert_to_indexed_bmp(input_image_path, output_bmp_path):
    img = Image.open(input_image_path)

    indexed_background_color = (0, 255, 0)

    img_with_indexed_background = Image.new("RGBA", img.size, indexed_background_color)
    img_with_indexed_background.paste(img, (0, 0), img)

    img_indexed = img_with_indexed_background.convert("RGB").convert("P", palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=256)

    img_indexed.save(output_bmp_path)

input_folder = "splash.png"
output_folder = "splash.bmp"


convert_to_indexed_bmp(input_folder, output_folder)
```

How to cut off this green edges?

Comment: Since BMP does not support transparency I wonder what your expected result is.

Comment: @KlausD. BMP does support transparency, btw.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Some programs interpret the first 8 bis in 32 bpp as transparency, but that's not part of the standard.

Comment: Please share your input and output images ***separately***.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't believe there is an official, up-to-date specification of BMP published by Microsoft or any standards authority.  The Library of Congress states as much https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000189.shtml So, IMHO, the format is defined by common example and however people use it. Wikipedia actually shows *"Example 2"* of a BMP file with alpha transparency so it is clearly possible to create such BMPs and is common usage in Windows, Apple software and **ImageMagick** and others  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Example_2

Comment: working sample [video](https://youtu.be/_bvGoTR9ngI), the file used on video is here:  [bmp file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AydA29SrkqySgf0gQCEJl457CUG7GEOM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell from your question what you actually want to do, but hopefully you can get what you want by reading the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load input image
im = Image.open('z.png')

# Create lime green  output image of same size
res = Image.new('RGBA', im.size, 'lime')

# Let's analyse the alpha channel
alpha = im.getchannel('A')
alpha.save('DEBUG-alpha.png')

# Derive new alpha channel, thresholding at 127
newAlpha = alpha.point(lambda p: 255 if p>127 else 0)
 
# Now paste image with new alpha onto background and save
res.paste(im, (0,0), newAlpha)
res.save('result.png')
```

This is `DEBUG-alpha.png`:

[image]

which shows your alpha values vary between 0 and 255. You seem to want to do something with the partially transparent pixels - but I can't tell if you want to make all of them fully transparent, or all of them fully opaque or maybe just some of them. Nor do I know why you paste onto a green background if you don't want green in your output image. Anyway, look at the line that says:

```
newAlpha = alpha.point(lambda p: 255 if p>127 else 0)
```

and change it according to what you need.

[image]

Maybe you want this:

```
newAlpha = alpha.point(lambda p: 0 if p>0 and p<140 else 255)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, what I need is bmp file with indexed colors and transparency, basically, png file is converted to 8 bit bmp file, a green background is set as color that should be transparent, my issue is that I couldn't set a threshold like you done to rip off partial transparent pixels, resulting in green edges. What I need is this: working sample [video](https://youtu.be/_bvGoTR9ngI), the file used on video is here:  [bmp file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AydA29SrkqySgf0gQCEJl457CUG7GEOM/view?usp=sharing)
I'm gonna try to use your solution, thanks!